# Processing - BufferedOutputStream exception

Tags: java, php, network-programming, processing

I'm a stranger to `Java`, but I'm developing an app with `Processing`, and I need enlightenment, please.

I'm running a `php server` on `127.0.0.1:8080` on the root of the `.pde` below. all my `php scripts` are bug free, as well as the rest of the Processing code.

after careful analysis, I've learned that the bug is in the function below.

what is the raised exception down under telling me? and how can I fix the code?

```
//(cont)

void postPicture(){
//load the saved image into an array of bytes
byte[] thisFile=loadBytes(fileName);

//open a new connection to the server
thisClient = new Client(this, "localhost", 80);
//make an HTTP POST request:
thisClient.write("POST " + pictureScriptUrl + " HTTP/1.1\n");
thisClient.write("Host: localhost\n");
//tell the server you're sending the POST in multiple parts
//and send a unique string that will delineate the parts
thisClient.write("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=");
thisClient.write(boundary + "\n");

//form the beginning of the request
String requestHead ="--" + boundary + "\n";
requestHead +="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; ";
requestHead += "filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\n";
requestHead +="Content-Type: image/jpeg\n\n";

//form the end of the request
String tail="\n\n--" + boundary + "--\n";

//calculate and send the length of the total request
//including the head of the request, the file, and the tail
int contentLength = requestHead.length() + thisFile.length + tail.length();
thisClient.write("Content-Length: " + contentLength + "\n\n");

//send the header of the request, the file and the tail
thisClient.write(requestHead);
thisClient.write(thisFile);
thisClient.write(tail);
}
```

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageOutputStream.close(FileCacheImageOutputStream.java:238)
at com.sun.imageio.stream.StreamCloser$CloseAction.performAction(StreamCloser.java:130)
at com.sun.imageio.stream.StreamCloser$1.run(StreamCloser.java:74)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What line results in this error?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I don't know, it is raised within Processing; is there a way of checking the exact line?

Comment: Maybe `println()` statements before each line? The last line to print out is the one that's throwing the NPE. How did you figure out that this method was the culprit?

Comment: I isolated the methods, and this one is the only one throwing it.